# Store files in different subdirectories using python

Tags: python, directory, directory-structure, folium

I have a pandas dataframe `df` that looks like this:

```
import pandas as pd
d = {'user': ['Peter', 'Peter', 'Peter', 'Peter', 'David', 'David', 'David', 'Emma', 'Joyce', 'Joyce', 'Joyce'], 'date': ['2019-03-04', '2019-03-04', '2019-03-04', '2019-03-04', '2019-03-04', '2019-03-04', '2019-03-04', '2019-03-04', '2019-03-04', '2019-03-04', '2019-03-04'], 'lat': [37.749798119650926, 37.751028173710736, 37.751698332490214, 37.75180012822952, 38.122893081890844, 38.124108467926035, 38.12743379574882, 37.89363489791644, 37.53620628385582, 37.53804390907164, 37.54044296272588], 'lon': [-122.49230146408082, -122.49229073524474, -122.49170064926147, -122.48974800109862, -122.24205136299133, -122.23907947540283, -122.23867177963257, -122.07653760910033, -121.99707984924316, -121.99315309524536, -121.9914150238037]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df

user    date        lat         lon
Peter   2019-03-04  37.749798   -122.492301
Peter   2019-03-04  37.751028   -122.492291
Peter   2019-03-04  37.751698   -122.491701
Peter   2019-03-04  37.751800   -122.489748
David   2019-03-04  38.122893   -122.242051
David   2019-03-04  38.124108   -122.239079
David   2019-03-04  38.127434   -122.238672
Emma    2019-03-04  37.893635   -122.076538
Joyce   2019-03-04  37.536206   -121.997080
Joyce   2019-03-04  37.538044   -121.993153
Joyce   2019-03-04  37.540443   -121.991415
```

Using the code below I'm able to create four separate folium maps grouped per user that show the coordinates on the map. The four map files are named after the user: `Peter.html`, `David.html`, `Emma.html` and `Joyce.html`.

```
import folium

users = list(df.user.unique())

def create_user_map(user):
    m = folium.Map(location=[37.733795, -122.446747], 
           zoom_start=9, 
           min_zoom=10, 
           max_zoom=19,
           control_scale=True)
 
    df_user = df[df.user==user]
    for row in df_user.itertuples():
         folium.CircleMarker( location=[row.lat, row.lon],
            radius=4,
            fill=True,
           fill_opacity=0.5).add_to(m)
    return m

for user in users:
    user_map = create_user_map(user)
    user_file = f"{user}.html"
    user_map.save(user_file)
```

Now I would like to automatically store these files in the corresponding subdirectories according to the folder structure below. How can I extend the loop above to achieve this?

```
Report/
└── Report_per_date/ 
    ├── 2019-03-01/
    ├── 2019-03-02/
    ├── 2019-03-03/
    └── 2019-03-04/
         └── Users/
             └── Peter/
                 └── Peter.html
             └── David/
                 └── David.html
             └── Emma/
                 └── Emma.html
             └── Joyce/
                 └── Joyce.html
```

I was hoping I could achieve this as follows:

```
import os
rootdir = pathlib.Path('./Report')
report_per_date = df.apply(lambda x: rootdir / 'Report_per_date' / x['date'] / 'Users' / x['user'] / f"{x['user']}.html", axis='columns')

for mapfile, data in df.groupby(report_per_date):
    mapfile.parent.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
    user_map = create_user_map(user)
    user_map.save(mapfile)
```

Unfortunately this is returning an `AttributeError: 'PosixPath' object has no attribute 'write'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change your loop to include dates, also create a 'path' column in your df.

```
df['path'] = df.apply(lambda x: rootdir / 'Report_per_date' / x['date'] / 'Users' / x['user'] / f"{x['user']}.html",
                      axis='columns')

dates = list(df.date.unique())


def create_user_map(df_user):
    m = folium.Map(location=[37.733795, -122.446747], 
               zoom_start=9, 
               min_zoom=10, 
               max_zoom=19,
               control_scale=True)
 
    for row in df_user.itertuples():
          folium.CircleMarker( location=[row.lat, row.lon],
                radius=4,
                fill=True,
                fill_opacity=0.5).add_to(m )
     
    return m

for user in users:
    for date in dates:
        data = df[(df.user==user)&(df.date==date)]
        path = data.iloc[0]['path']        
        path.parent.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)            
        user_map = create_user_map(data)
        user_map.save(str(path))
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried the code on my machine, and got a similar problem but got `AttributeError: 'WindowsPath' object has no attribute 'write'`

It appears Folium uses the module branca to do the saving to HTML, and it appears that branca cannot write to a path object. I can get it fixed by converting the path to a string:

```
user_map.save(str(mapfile))
```

That fixes the issue on my machine, and because you got user_map.save() working before when using a string this will likely work for you too.

Also, in the snippet below you are calling the create_user_map on the variable user.

```
for mapfile, data in df.groupby(report_per_date):
    mapfile.parent.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
    user_map = create_user_map(user)
    user_map.save(mapfile)
```

But this will always be Joyce in this example, because this is left over from the `for user in users:` part above this. An idea is to get the user from the path in the loop like so:

```
for mapfile, data in df.groupby(report_per_date):
    mapfile.parent.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
    user_map = create_user_map(mapfile.stem)
    user_map.save(str(mapfile))
```

This works because .stem returns the name of the file without extension.